# Null Pointer Exception within DialogFragments, android

Tags: java, android, dialog, onclick, nullpointerexception

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public class ChooseNumWorkoutsDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {
    Button btnClose, btnFinished;
    NumberPicker np;

    public ChooseNumWorkoutsDialog() {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_numpicker, container);
        getDialog().setTitle("Number of Exercises");
        btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        btnFinished = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFinished);
        np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np);
        //np.setMaxValue(20);
        //np.setMinValue(1);
        //np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
        //btnClose.setOnClickListener(this);
        //btnFinished.setOnClickListener(this);   
        return view;
    }
```

The XML file does contain all referenced buttons and numberPickers. When this is run, a Null Pointer exception is found at "np.setMaxValue(20);", the only way I can get it to work is if I comment out all of the commented out parts you see.

- Is there some rule that I don't know of that states I can't set up my onclick listeners etc within a dialogfragment?
- What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize your views in [onActivityCreated()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29). From documentation:

> Called when the fragment's activity has been created **and this
>   fragment's view hierarchy instantiated. It can be used to do final
>   initialization once these pieces are in place, such as retrieving
>   views** or restoring state. It is also useful for fragments that use
>   setRetainInstance(boolean) to retain their instance, as this callback
>   tells the fragment when it is fully associated with the new activity
>   instance. This is called after onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup,
>   Bundle) and before onStart().

Than you can call `getView().findViewById(R.id.np);`

or use `np = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.np);` in `onCreateView()`, notice the "**view.**"